# Line chart with draggable point using Streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, altair

I would like to do a line chart with draggable point using Streamlit like the following example :

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20703207/77322131-8a47f800-6d13-11ea-9ca8-b9fc7f820e85.gif

I need to get the value of the different points in a DataFrame to use theses values in a model.
I currently have an alternative solution using a vertical slider (https://github.com/sqlinsights/streamlit-vertical-slider), but that is not very user friendly.

Here is my current code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import  streamlit_vertical_slider  as svs
import altair as alt

hours = [i for i in range(4,22)]
values_original = [0,3,9,25,62,25,30,30,45,45,28,21,40,55,55,30,10,5,0]
values=values_original
df_original = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(hours, values_original)),
       columns =['hours', 'Values'])

sliders = {}
columns = st.columns(len(hours))

for idx, i in enumerate(hours):
    key = 'member'+str(idx)
    with columns[idx]:
        sliders['slider'+str(key)] = svs.vertical_slider(key=key, default_value=values[idx], step=1, min_value=0, max_value=100)
        if sliders['slider'+str(key)] == None:
            sliders['slider'+str(key)]= values[idx]
        values[idx]=float(sliders['slider'+str(key)])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(hours, values_original)),
       columns =['hours', 'Values'])

df['Type']='project'

df_original['Type']='reference'

bar = alt.Chart(df).mark_area(opacity=0.7,interpolate='cardinal').encode(
    x=alt.X('hours',axis=alt.Axis(title='hours'),scale=alt.Scale(domain=[4, 22])),
    y=alt.Y('Values:Q'),
    tooltip=['hours', alt.Tooltip('Values')],
    fill=alt.Fill(field='Type',title='Courbe : '))

bar_original = alt.Chart(df_original).mark_line(color='red',interpolate='cardinal',opacity=0.7).encode(
    x=alt.X('hours',axis=alt.Axis(title='hours'),scale=alt.Scale(domain=[4, 22])),
    y=alt.Y('Values:Q'),
    tooltip=['hours', alt.Tooltip('Values')],
    opacity=alt.Opacity(field='Type',title=None))


st.altair_chart(bar+bar_original, use_container_width=True)
```

and my current result :
[image]

Comment: Does the `streamlit-vertical-slider` give values on the points?

Comment: Sure i can get the value of the vertical slide (ie. 0,3,9 etc...).

Comment: Nice, your issue is `that is not very user friendly`. I wonder why that is not user friendly? I read the streamlit road map, charting is on it, getting points, interactive, etc.

Comment: Because I had more points than in my exemple and i cannot put slider just abose the specific point. Moreover, I can have few curve on the same graph

Comment: How about splitting the plot horizontally. There are sections [4, 6], [6, 8], etc. The user will adjust the slider per section. Also add the overall plot without slider, so that the user can see the plot overview.

Comment: The first example you show is just perfect for what I am trying to achieve. I only see the gif though, who made it?

Comment: @Mianen here is the git : https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata