# Draggable points in Streamlit

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, bokeh, streamlit

I would like to create a scatter plot, but can drag and drop the points vertically. I also need the values of the points. Something like this:

[image: Matplotlib plot with draggable points]

But I need to integrate it with Streamlit. I've tried Plotly, Matplotlib and Bokeh, but none of them worked.
I really prefer a custom plot in Plotly, but I don't know how to move the points.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: If you wouldn't mind editing the data (rather than moving the points), then you could use an editable dataframe to live-change the values. The graph should respond to your edits in real time

Comment: Bokeh has a built in point edit tool. Are you saying you tried that, and it didn’t work? If so, you have to share code and actual details about what didn’t work, to get help on SO. Otherwise it seems like something you should try.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see currently this is not (yet) supported in Streamlit using only Python. This is taken from other fora and the Streamlit documentation:

- [Streamlit forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/add-draggable-matplotlibplot-inside-streamlit/17792)
- [Plotly forum on drag and drop](https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-drag-and-drop-effects-to-a-plotly-map/72500/10)

Alternatives that should work at the moment are:

- [Manipulate the underlying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74601019/line-chart-with-draggable-point-using-streamlit)
- [Use streamlit-plotly-events](https://github.com/null-jones/streamlit-plotly-events).